# How to use username as author instead of real name in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When doing things via the web interface of GitHub such as merging pull requests or working on gh-pages, the author of the commit is:

```
real name <email@address>
```

but I would like it to be:

```
username <email@address>
```

Is there a way to change this?

When working on my local repo and push from here, everything is as expected.

**Edit**

Here are some simple steps to reproduce the issue:

- create a new repo and mark the checkbox to generate the README.md file (this creates a commit)
- clone the repo
- in your local repo run `$ git log` and notice that the real name was used for the commit done in GitHub, and not the username

Here is a test repo (I will delete it again later): https://github.com/puce77/test

**Edit 2**

Or is it recommended to use the real name? For what reason? I think the username is unique but the real name might be not. Also real names change more likely (eg. marriage) than usernames.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @mipadi Another update

Comment: I have the same issue, commits pushed from local repo use my proper username while all operations done from the web interface use my real name. This make commits appear like they where made by two different persons when running `git log`.

Comment: It seems like GitHub Desktop defaults to real name over username. I wonder if I should go with it, or continue to use usernames.

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers are all valid for git but since you are asking for edits from GitHub:

GitHub commits use the name you specified in `Settings > Public profile > Name` (first settings page). You do not have to specify your name here.

Note that what actually matters is the email (i.e. when you sign with GPG keys). You can use the mail GitHub associates with your account which is `<username>@users.noreply.github.com` which will not change. You can enable it by ticking `Settings > Email > Keep my email addresses private`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question:

> How to use username as author instead of real name in GitHub?

You are looking for a bad practice.

Answer:

**Manually way**

```
# For global configuration on your PC.
git config --global user.name "your_username"

# For local configuration on your client repository
git config --global user.name "your_username"
```

(this is bad practice)

Original best practice,

```
# For global configuration on your PC.
git config --global user.name "Your fullname"

# For local configuration on your client repository
git config --global user.name "Your fullname"
```

**Automatic way:** No solution existing, and Git or GitHub don't recommend this, (a simple logic, when GitHub has email address, GitHub can inferring according account's username.

**Find your information:** Let's type command

```
git config --list
```

you will see, the Git designers didn't recommend, or design an information field for **username**, just **`user.name`**

Answer (score 0):

**Attention** This command changes the committer data in every commit where OLD_EMAIL is old@email on username new@email. Because of this change, SHA1 commits git push require -f(force)

```sh
git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="old@email"
CORRECT_NAME="username"
CORRECT_EMAIL="new@email"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
   export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
   export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
   export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
   export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags

git push -f
```

Comment: Thanks, but question was more about new commits with the web interface.

Answer (score -1):

Your username associates your commits with an identity. To set it on a local repository use the following command:

```
git config user.name "Your name"
```

To set it globally for every repository on your computer:

```
git config --global user.name "Your name"
```

All according to the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

Comment: I'm aware of this and as I said it works using the local repo. But I have the issue with the web interface.

Comment: My git tool went so far as to override these values. Check your settings.

Comment: AFAICT, this question is about making commits through the Github web interface, not making changes locally then pushing. In this case, Github itself is the "git tool".

Answer (score -1):

You may add your username as a co-author, it doesn't solve the problem but may help. An example: https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors#creating-co-authored-commits-on-github